# JqueryUi - Tabs / Ajax Content / jqueryui.com/demos

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I could not figure out how does the follow ajax work, (from http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html )

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a
href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a
href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a
href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-3">Tab 3(slow)</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a
href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-4">Tab 4(broken)</a>
</li>

.....

<div id="ui-tabs-1"
class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
<div id="ui-tabs-2"
class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
```

when click for example Tab 2, to go to  "http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html#ui-tabs-2", that is  an empty div, so how did the background code(e.g. PHP) did to get #ui-tabs-2 and return http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax/content2.html
thanks

Comment: Its real simple in that demo, they dont create a div for tabs 2-4, only a li(the tab itself, not the panel). Inside the li is a link element with a href to the page to put in the panel, thus when clicked on the page is loaded into the tab via ajax "auto-magically"

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you added does not comply with the sample page at http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html

It should look something like:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

First tab is not an ajax tab. Other tabs are dynamically loaded through ajax. `href` determines target content for ajax fetch.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but if you Inspect Element "Tab 2", you got <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#ui-tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>    the href is "#ui-tabs-2", beside that, could you please point out which function is called to load the contents, thanks a lot

Comment: When you inspect the tab using some inspection tool say Firebug you see updated tags after ajax fetch. jQuery reads the remote content dynamically and adds it to DOM then updates tags accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I am a rookie, I am confused about "updated tags after ajax fetch", is there any example I could refer to? I saved the whole page and got the same href as I pointed out. then  I put <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li> in my own tests, then inspected it, then I still saw the same thing I put in herf

Comment: jQuery updates DOM while viewing/running the page in browser and you see last updated DOM when inspecting the page at a moment. This is the general case but I don't have enough data to say what happens at your side.